# openVPN accesses the K8S cluster, it access the POD of the host where the server is located,cannot access the POD of other hosts in the cluster

Tags: kubernetes, openvpn

I deployed the OpenVPN server in the K8S cluster and deployed the OpenVPN client on a host outside the cluster. However, when I use client access, I can only access the POD on the host where the OpenVPN server is located, but cannot access the POD on other hosts in the cluster.
The network used by the cluster is Calico. I also added the following iptables rules to the openVPN server host in the cluster:

I found that I did not receive the package back when I captured the package of tun0 on the server.

Comment: `openvpn Server Configuration:
    port 1194
    proto tcp
    dev tun0
    ca ca.crt
    cert youmen.crt 
    key youmen.key  
    dh dh1024.pem
    server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0 
    keepalive 10 60
    comp-lzo
    user nobody
    group nobody
    persist-key
    persist-tun
    status openvpn-status.log
    log         openvpn.log
    verb 3
    push "route 172.30.0.0 255.255.0.0"
    push "route 10.254.0.0 255.255.0.0"`

Comment: `Client Configuration:
    client
    dev tun0
    #port 1194
    proto tcp
    #remote-cert-tls server
    remote 172.20.47.95 1194  tcp
    #resolv-retry infinite
    nobind
    #route 172.30.0.0 255.255.0.0
    #mute-replay-warnings
    #redirect-gateway def1
    key-direction 1
    ca  /etc/openvpn/client/ca.crt
    cert /etc/openvpn/client/yonyou.crt
    key /etc/openvpn/client/yonyou.key
    comp-lzo 
    persist-key
    persist-tun`

Comment: `I also added the following iptables rules to the openVPN server host in the cluster:
    4    MASQUERADE  all  --  10.8.0.0/24          anywhere`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How did you setup your Kubernetes cluster? How did you deployed OpenVPN server - could you share some steps / instructions that you followed? Please, instead of pasting commands / logs in comments edit your post and make it readable.

Answer (score 1):

When the server is deployed on hostnetwork, a forward rule is missing in the iptables field.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you set up iptables inside the server pod as iptables/netfilter was not accessible on most kube clusters I saw.

If you want to have full access to cluster networking over that OpenVPN server you probably want to use `hostNetwork: true` on your vpn server. The problem is that you still need proper MASQ/SNAT rule to get response across to your client.

You should investigate your traffic going out of the server pod to see if it has a properly rewritten source address, otherwise the nodes in cluster will have no knowledge on how to route the response.

You probably have a common gateway for your nodes, depending on your kube implementation you might get around this issue by setting the route back to your vpn, but that likely will require some scripting around vpn server it self to make sure the route is updated each time server pod is rescheduled.